# Work Item created and ordered first in the backlogs using Azure Devops Rest API

Tags: python, azure-devops

using azure devops rest api how can I ensure that when I create a work item it is ordered as the first one in the backlog?

I want that for certain work items i create using the api that when its created it the work item will be the first one in the backlog.

does anyone know if this is possible?

Im using python and the requests library to create my work items. My code to create a work item is below.

```
def create_inquiry(ticket_id,df):
    create_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
        'Accept': 'application/json-patch+json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
        }     
    create_data = [
        
        {
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/System.Title",
            "from": None,
            "value": f"{df.loc[ticket_id, 'title']}"
        },
        {
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/Custom.Solving" ,
            "from": None,
            "value": f"{df.loc[ticket_id,'description']}"
        },
        {
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/Custom.Tickets",
            "from": None,
            "value": f"{ticket_id}"
        },
        {
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/System.State",
            "from": None,
            "value": "To do"
        },   
        {
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
            "from": None,
            "value": f"{df.loc[ticket_id,'collaborator']}"
        }
        ,{
            "op":"add",
            "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
            "from": None,
            "value": f"{df.loc[ticket_id,'priority_id']}"
        }
        ,
        
    ]

    response = requests.post(create_url, headers=create_headers,json=create_data)
    # print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response = response.json()
        df.loc[ticket_id,"HasWI"] = True
        print(response['id'])
        df.loc[ticket_id,"WorkItem_Id"] = response['id']
        # link_work_item(ticket_id,response['id'])
    else:
        print("error")
```

Comment: can you share the code that you have already tried ?

Comment: @Rafael Rubenstein Is there any update about this issue? feel free to let me know if the  answer can give you some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using azure devops rest api how can I ensure that when I create a work item it is ordered as the first one in the backlog?

When creating a work item via Rest API, I'm afraid we can't use parameters to put the work item at the first place in the backlog at the same time.

To meet your requirement, you can running the following Rest Api after the create work item API to reorder the work item.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/{Team}/_apis/work/workitemsorder?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{"ids":[newworkitemid],"iterationPath":"net5Project","previousId":0,"parentId":0}
```

Then the work item will move to the top of the Backlog.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Workitemsorder - Reorder Backlog Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/workitemsorder/reorder-backlog-work-items?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)